# Call to a member function - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to do login page with session but face a problem.

First i created a model called giris. the model giris has a function girisKontrol

```
  function girisKontrol($username, $password) {
        $sha1_password = sha1($password);
        $query = "SELECT id FROM pasaj_register WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$sha1_password."'";

        $result = $this->db->query($query, array($username, $sha1_password));

        if ($result->num_rows() == 1)
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and in a controller called giris

wrote below code,

```
public function main_page() {


        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $userID = $this->giris->girisKontrol($username,$password);

        if (!$userID) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('login error', TRUE);

            redirect('giris/giris');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
                'userID' => $userID));



            redirect('welcome_message');
        }
    }
```

however when form is processed. i take below error,

[image]

What's the reason ?

Comment: Well, what is line #19 in `controllers/giris`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't loaded the `giris` model.

Put something like this inside the constructor of the controller or at the top of the function call of the controller to load the model.

```
$this->load->model('giris');
```

Comment: i addeed $this->load->model('giris/giris'); to constructor for locating my model but it also gives error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class giris in C:\xampp\htdocs\pasaj\application\models\giris\giris.php on line 21 and the line 21 is this $userID = $this->giris->girisKontrol($username,$password);

Comment: @MertMETİN it might be better if you could update the question with the new code. Also, have you loaded the model somewhere else? The error is saying that there's already a defined property with the name `giris` within the object. It could be something else other than a model though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to load your model:

Invoke

```
$this->load->model('giris');
```

prior to

```
$userID = $this->giris->girisKontrol($username,$password);
```

Comment: i addeed $this->load->model('giris/giris'); to constructor for locating my model but it also gives error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class giris in C:\xampp\htdocs\pasaj\application\models\giris\giris.php on line 21 and the line 21 is this $userID = $this->giris->girisKontrol($username,$password);

Comment: Did you follow Code Igniter conventions and name your model class Giris_model ?  It sounds like you have multiple classes named "Giris" and they are now conflicting.

Comment: the problem is that your class and your model has the same name...change your class to something like girisVO...

Comment: @Gerep - this should be the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your class and your model has the same name...change your class to something like `girisVO`, report back